# How to Create crystal reports pages

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

I have a database table with columns cannot fit on 1 page of crystal reports.
Do I have to create a sub report to be able to accommodate the rest of the column?
If I stretch the length of the form in the designer, I see a page 2 in the preview but can't 
see it in the design view.

Comment: There is no need to add sub report, is the number of columns in large and you are not able to put them in detail section?

Comment: @ Iti Tyagi Yes Sir, info like name, birthdate, etc cannot fit into the width of the repor.

Comment: Adding the sub report will not make any change as the width will be same for the main report and the sub report.

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation of the report to landscape and decrease the font size, change a font family to smaller size one like verdana etc.
In order to change the orientation:

1)Right click on the report> design > change the orientation from potrait to landscape.

2)Change the font size of the textobject- right click on text object> format object> Font tab